# Как в OpenGL захватить пиксели до отрисовки текущего шейдера? Подскажите Аналог GrabPass-а из шейдера из Unity(язык HLSL) для OpenGL (язык GLSL)

Tags: unity3d, opengl, glsl, hlsl

Подскажите аналогичную технологию GrabPass-а из шейдера из Unity(язык HLSL) для OpenGL (язык GLSL).

Вот [пример](https://m.habr.com/ru/post/427357/) как это делается в Unity:

> Этот проход захватит изображение на экране в текстуру _GrabTexture. Текстура будет содержать только то, что было отрисовано до того, как наш объект, использующий этот шейдер, пошёл на отрисовку.

В OpenGL нашел только способ отрисовать все в другом фреймбуфере, потом взять оттуда пиксели и отрисовать нужную обработку в новом фреймбуфере, который уже выведется на экран. Это накладно при множестве постобработок. И по неизвестным причинам получилось только когда отрисовал заново в итоговый фреймбуфер все с первого фреймбуфера и далее пошел на отрисовку объект с постобработкой занимающий только часть экрана в отличии от примеров с инета с постобработкой на весь экран

Вот пример с двумя фреймбуферами и третим результирующим: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44779142/opengl-es-2-0-gaussian-blur-on-triangle

Неужели в OpenGL нет технологии GrabPass? Ведь HLSL переводится в итоги в бинарный GLSL для Android например.

Задача: Постобработка(написание шейдера 1.с эффектом стекла; 2.Gaussian blur)

В CubeMapping пример с текстурой на заднем плане, А нужно захватить не только текстуру а обьекты OpenGL - и преломить свет на них тоже.

Comment: *"В OpenGL нашел только способ отрисовать все в другом фреймбуфере - протом взять оттуда пиксели и отрисовать нужную обработку в новом фреймбуфере - который уже выведется на экран."* - тем не менее оно так и делается. по-человечески это называется render to texture

Comment: Спасибо за наводку. В Unity(HLSL) прямо в шейдере можно написать " GrabPass{"_Texture1"} ". Можно ли как-то также написать в OpenGL(GLSL) подключенным через C++ Движок - в инете на эту тему ничего нет. И дает ли подход Юнити большое преимущество. Выбираю движок между Unity и Cocos2d-x. В юнити экран-заставка ограничительный если Юнити бесплатен. Но если он превосходит нативный opengl es(целевая платформа Android И iOS(Metal) ), то лучше наверно писать в Unity.

Comment: Есть предположение, что GrabPass это просто синтаксический сахар так как все в итоге компилится(переводится) в бинарный GLSL(или чтото вроде этого) для нативной платформы Opengl ES вот этой штуковиной: https://github.com/microsoft/ShaderConductor Но почему тогда GrabPass прямо в теле шейдера пишется..

Comment: Unity работает исключительно поверх платформенного opengles и привносит значительный оверхед во многих сценариях, GrabPass в шейдере (который идет внутри HLSLPROGRAM) напрямую никак не участвует.